# How to trust a non Domain PC over a VPN connected via a Domain Account for SQL Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, windows-authentication, active-directory, cross-domain

We are trying to enable a windows login to SQL Server from an untrusted laptop.

- The SQL Server has been enabled to allow the domain account to login and browse the data
- When a domain user connects to the VPN via domain PC (over the internet) they can connect successfully

So we have a guest on non domain pc non on a domain.

- Local user logs on to PC
- Connects to the VPN (using domain credentials)

when trying to browse the fileserver (same as SQL Server) they get:

- The User is not allowed to login from this Workstation

when trying to browse the SQL Server they get:

- Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication

I've done some reseach on the latter message but no links I found talk about our non domain to domain user.

**Am I right in thinking that once a user connects to the VPN they impersonate the domain user?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok we have a solution.

In Active Directory User and Computers Snapin:

- Select the **User** and right-click Properties
- Select the **Account** Tab
- Click the **Log On To** button
- In the **Logon Workstations** dialog, add the name of the untrusted PC

Ok and apply as appropirate. Close the VPN, and restart the connection.